How can I use GLPI to get open tickets filtered by user_id?
Everyone, I'm having trouble filtering open tickets for a single user. I don't quite understand how the criteria work, and it always shows me all the tickets. Can someone show me how to filter only the open tickets for a specific user using cURL?
I tried to filter open tickets by performing a GET request on Ticket_User and then another GET request on {....'links': [{'rel': 'Ticket'....}]}, filtering by status, but this takes too long. I would like to know how to apply a direct filter in the URL.
